# How to I create a prominent AppBar in React?

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui, jsx, appbar

I just started using React and Material-UI.

When looking at the design guidelines, I found a very nice looking AppBar (a `prominent` AppBar, that's how they call it).

I'd like to add such a prominent AppBar to my site.

However, [when looking at the API](https://material-ui.com/api/app-bar/), it doesn't say anything about how to implement this `prominent` feature, although it appears various times [on their sites](https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web-catalog/#/component/top-app-bar).

What I've tried so far? I know how to create a basic AppBar with some Typography and Icon components, that's all.

Comment: I don't think that the material-ui library is providing this kind of prominent AppBar. The demo you linked is part of the material-components project, which seems to be something else. (Even if both are based on Google's Material UI guidelines)

Comment: Ok. So where else shall I have a look then if I‘d like to implement exactly such a prominent AppBar? @ArnaudChrist

Comment: I'm not aware of a third-party library providing this component. So I guess you have 2 solutions here. Or you browse the web to find one, or you develop it yourself  :)